# How do i test that an object is an instance of a particular class in D?

Tags: instance, equality, d

How do i test that an object is an instance of a particular class in D?

Something akin to Javascript's `instanceof` keyword?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `cast`.  It returns a null reference when you attempt to cast to a subclass it isn't an instance of (like C++'s dynamic_cast).

```d
auto a = new Base;
auto b = cast(Child) a;
assert(b is null);

a = new Child;
auto c = cast(Child) a;
assert(c !is null);
```

Answer (score 4):

[typeid expression](http://www.d-programming-language.org/expression.html#TypeidExpression) can tell you if instance is of some exact type (without considering inheritance hierarchy):

```
class A {}

class B : A {}

void main()
{
        A a = new B();
        // dynamic
        assert( typeid(a) == typeid(B) );
        // static
        assert( typeid(typeof(a)) == typeid(A) );
}
```

Comment: That could be used to check whether an object is _exactly_ a particularly type, not whether it's an instance of a particular type. `typeid(a) == typeid(A)` would be `false`. There's nothing "cleaner" about it. It's checking something quite different.

Comment: Ah, beg my pardon then, misunderstood wording. For me "is exactly of a type" == "is instance of a type", looks like I need to improve my English :(

Upvoted eco's answer.

Comment: @Михаил Страшун Well, it's programming terminology more than general English, and it can be a bit confusing. But generally the term "instance of" refers to whether a type is a particular type or is derived from that type as opposed to whether it's _exactly_ that type.

Comment: So, one could use assert(typeid(a).base == typeid(B).base); as well, right?

Comment: Could use for what exactly? typeid(a).base == typeid(B).base == typeid(A) in case of my snippet, true. But it helps not to solve "instanceof" question - in case of class hierarchy more complex you would have need to check typeid of bases in a loop until checked one is found or Object is reached. Quite excessive, in my opinion.

Comment: There can only ever be one base class. Multiple inheritance is only for interfaces. So checking if the base classes are equal is, afaik, the same as checking if one is instanceof the other.