# Is instance castable to class

Tags: d

```
class A { this() { } }
class B : A { this() { } }
auto b = new B()
if(b.IsCastableTo(A)) {
    //...
}
```

How would I check if b can be casted to type A?

Comment: Instances of `B` is **always** castable to `A`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i test that an object is an instance of a particular class in D?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994076/how-do-i-test-that-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-particular-class-in-d)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the D manual you would do:

```
if (cast(A) b) { 
  // b is an instance of A 
} else { 
  // b is not an instance of A 
}
```

**References:**

- [Expressions in D](http://dlang.org/expression.html#CastExpression)